# In Visual Basic (Excel) Columns select too many columns

Tags: excel, vba, select

In an Excel macro, I'm trying to select & hide a number of columns, using the code

```
Columns("D:N").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

But for unknown reasons, the Columns("D:N").Select selects column D through V, inclusive.  I looked and there are no merged cells, and even if there were, that shouldn't stop me from hiding the selected (intended) columns.

Any hint why Columns("D:N").Select selects columns D through V inclusive?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you do `Columns("D:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True`?

Comment: Are any of your columns Hidden ?

Comment: test with only one macro of 2 line code,with blank sheet

Comment: You might try running through your code with 'F8' (Windows) or through the Debug>Step Into and seeing if it selects correctly. I personally try very hard to avoid using 'Select' if at all possible, as it often doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That Columns("D:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True works.  I suspect that I'll never know what it didn't work originally.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have horizontally-merged cells extending beyond Col N to col V

Answer (score 0):

I ran those two lines in a blank macro on a blank sheet and it worked fine, so I believe the problem lies in other parts of the code

Can you try putting this right before those 2 lines?

```
SendKeys "{ESC}"
```

If this works then it's likely that an earlier portion of your macro had a SELECT statement that stuck around.